# finding only files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

```
find / \ -newer $1
```

Above is the code I have so far. I am trying to make find find all files newer then the argument 1 while only staying in the current directory. I have tried various ways of using prune but I cant seem to find one that works. Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: What's the backslash for?  It doesn't do anything given that command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the `-maxdepth 1` flag.  Why are you using `find /` if you want to operate on the current directory?  It should be something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -newer $1
```

Comment: I was putting that after -newer for so long... thank you !

EDIT : Is there anyway to restrict to only files though?

Comment: It should work fine after, too.  My linux `find` gives me a warning about it though.  To restrict to regular files, add a `-type f`.